# Separate columns by commas ignoring nulls

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below table:

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | null | C1 | null | E1 |
| A2 | B2 | C2 | null | null |
| null | null | C3 | null | E3 |

I would like the below output (separated by commas, if any value is null, then do not add a comma):

| F |
| --- |
| A1, C1, E1 |
| A2, B2, C2 |
| C3, E3 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate all columns regardless of whether they are null or not (saving a lot of comparisons to null), but then fix the commas with string functions. Whether this will be faster or slower than checking each value individually for being null will depend on the data (how many columns - I assume 5 is just for illustration - and how frequent `null` is in the data, for example).

I included more data for testing in the `with` clause (which, obviously, is not part of the answer; remove it and use your actual table and column names).

```
with
  inputs (a, b, c, d, e) as (
    select 'A1', null, 'C1', null, 'E1' from dual union all
    select 'A2', 'B2', 'C2', null, null from dual union all
    select null, null, 'C3', null, 'E3' from dual union all
    select null, null, null, null, null from dual union all
    select null, 'B5', null, null, null from dual
  )
select a, b, c, d, e,
       regexp_replace(
         trim (both ',' from a || ',' || b || ',' || c || ',' || d || ',' || e)
         , ',+', ', ') as f
from   inputs;

A    B    C    D    E    F              
---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---------------
A1        C1        E1   A1, C1, E1     
A2   B2   C2             A2, B2, C2     
          C3        E3   C3, E3         
                                        
     B5                  B5
```

**EDIT**

In a comment, the OP expanded the scope of the question. The new requirement is to also remove leading and/or trailing whitespace from the input tokens (including ignoring tokens altogether, if they consist entirely of whitespace).

This can be achieved as follows:

```
select a, b, c, d, e,
       ltrim(
         rtrim(
           regexp_replace(
             a || ',' || b || ',' || c || ',' || d || ',' || e
             , '[[:space:]]*,[,[:space:]]*', ', '
           )
           , ', ' || chr(9)
         )
         , ', ' || chr(9)
       ) as f
from   inputs;
```

Comment: Thanks, this goes much faster! Is there any way of, if the null columns instead of being null, they are space, tab... not consider them without manually trimming thm in the concatenation?

Comment: @jeiv - Will your next question be, "if the inputs have leading or trailing spaces or tabs, can we remove those as well"? If it is, then please say so now, since both questions can be answered together. However, if such whitespace around actual text should **not** be removed, the answer to the first question (the one you did ask) will be different.

Comment: yeah, I had not thought of that, but removing the leading/trailing spaces would be ideal.

Comment: could I have a brief explanation on what do the 'both' and the [[:space:]]*  inside the regexp_replace do?

Comment: `trim` functions come in a few versions, including `ltrim` and `rtrim`. `trim(both <character> from <string>)` trims the given character from both ends of a string, but it only works for one character. `ltrim` and `rtrim` can remove more than one character, but only from one end of the string. In any case, you can remove the inner `trim(',' from both....)` from the query, since now I have `ltrim` and `rtrim` after the regular expression anyway (and they **are** indeed needed, I can't remove them). That actually makes the query simpler and slightly more efficient.

Comment: `[[:space:]]` is the POSIX "space" character class - meaning space, tab, line feed, carriage return, form feed, and/or vertical tab. All the "whitespace" characters that you want removed from the beginning and/or the end of each token. In the regular expression, I replace every occurrence of (zero or more whitespace characters) followed by a comma followed by (zero or more commas and/or whitespace characters) with exactly one comma and one space.

Comment: @jeiv - I edited again to remove the `trim(both ',' from ...)` which is not needed anymore.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the masterclass!

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you want `concat_ws()` -- which Oracle does not support.  Instead, you can use:

```
select trim(',' from
             (case when A is not null then ',' || A end ||
              case when B is not null then ',' || B end ||
              case when C is not null then ',' || C end ||
              case when D is not null then ',' || D end ||
              case when E is not null then ',' || E end
             )
           )
```